# How to join two tables with two conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

LLOAN

```
LOANID SOURCEID LOAN_COMPANY ETC
1      1        3
2      1        3
3      1        1
4      2        1
5      2        1
6      2        1
7      3        1
8      3        1
```

COMPANY

```
CompanyID CountryID CompanyIDLLAS 
1         1         1
2         1         2
3         1         3
4         2         1
5         3         1
6         4         1
```

And I want to join them. The SourceID refers to the CountryID and the LOAN_COMPANY refers to the CompanyID. Only country '1' has multiple companies, all the others just have one.

How can I join these two tables correctly? I've tried many different things, of which this came the closest:

```
SELECT Count(c.CompanyID) FROM dbo.LLOAN As l
LEFT JOIN dbo.Company As c ON c.CountryID = l.SourceID AND c.CompanyID = l.LOAN_COMPANY
```

But it leaves many rows blank. What is the correct way to join two tables with two conditions?

Comment: if you want exact match from both tables then remove LEFT from the query just JOIN

Comment: How did you get two similar columns in Company Table ? *CompanyID* i mean

Comment: You will need to learn about about `JOIN`... this is a great article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins

Comment: @The, I'm sorry, the last colum has another name; it's now right in the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below Query:

```
SELECT Count(c.CompanyID) 
FROM dbo.LLOAN As LL
LEFT JOIN dbo.Company As C 
ON (C.CountryID = LL.SourceID) 
AND (C.CompanyID = LL.LOAN_COMPANY)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for the most part, but there is one more problem: Some

Comment: @BasDeBeer:- What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can group the condition using paranthesis like this:

```
SELECT Count(c.CompanyID) 
FROM dbo.LLOAN As l
LEFT JOIN dbo.Company As c ON (c.CountryID = l.SourceID) AND (c.CompanyID = l.LOAN_COMPANY)
```